# Font used in Quicksilver - Large Text?

Tags: macos, quicksilver

I want to use the font used in the Quicksilver large text display.

Is it Monaco? But I see a difference between Monaco used in the application and in Quicksilver LargeText.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Lucida Grande.

Comment: no...the single quote looks different between "Large Text" and Monaco/Lucida Grande.

Comment: If you look at [the code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#dXKTFGuz97A/trunk/Crucible/Code/QSLargeTypeDisplay.m&q=QSShowLargeType%20package:http://blacktree-alchemy%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=15), you'll see it's using a bold version of whatever your system font is.  By default, the system font is Lucida Grande.  If you have some kind of theme changer that changes the system font, that font is what it will use.